# Fixing Spiral Topology

Tags: mesh, sculpting, topology

Trying to create an all quad mesh and I keep getting these spirals in my topology.  Any good tips on getting rid of spirals like this?[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Go into edge mode <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> and <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> select the spiraling edge loop. Follow it untill you hit a pole vertex with an uneven edge count.
   [image: spiraling edge loop]
2. Starting from the pole vertex, <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> select the chain of vertices which is perpendicular to the spiraling loop. <kbd>V</kbd> Rip them, then make new faces F joining the correct vertices on both sides.
   [image]

Still images of step 2 (for clarity):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]